# Can't skip .net strong name verification on windows

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

I have tried to skip .net strong name verification on both Win10 & Win7, following 
[How to disable strong name validation](https://bensonxion.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/how-to-disable-strong-name-validation/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218572/strange-problems-about-strong-name-verification-skipping), type the following comamnds on both x86 and amd64 environment.

```
vcvarsall.bat amd64
sn /Vr *
vcvarsall.bat x86
sn /Vr *
```

but still receive the complains:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = US\Hauck
LOG: DisplayName = TestDll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1cf2005f5cbe0bd (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/myprojects/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : TestDriver, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1cf2005f5cbe0bd.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: TestDll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1cf2005f5cbe0bd
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/myprojects/bin/TestDll.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN 
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

After googling a lot I still have no idea how to skip the verification.

References:

1. [How to: Enable a 64-Bit Visual C++ Toolset on the Command Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx)
2. [Bypassing strong-name verification for a .Net assembly](http://www.lookout.net/2006/04/bypassing-strong-name-verification-for.html)
3. [How to: Disable the Strong-Name Bypass Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are chasing the wrong solution, the problem is that the Interop.PCOMMSERVERLib.dll file found at runtime isn't the same as the one you compiled your program with.  Which isn't unusual, it isn't that obvious that you have to use the /keyfile option in Tlbimp.exe.  Particularly so if that wasn't done by you.  Whatever you did next to fix the compiler error got you in trouble.  Fix the problem by copying the modified interop dll, preferably always by using Copy Local = True.  And update your tooling, no reason left to still need interop libraries today.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @Hans, I have update my log now, the strong names of reference testdll.dll and runtime testdll.dll differ, I use it to test skipping of verification, and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Again, it doesn't have anything to do with strong name validation.  The assembly name is different.  You can normally write a bindingRedirect in the app.exe.config file to force a match but that does not work in the specific case of the PublicKeyToken being null.  The solution is far too simple to lose any sleep over, an interop assembly doesn't contain any code so just copy the correct dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key token is part of an assembly identity. That means that if you have two assemblies:

TestDriver, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1cf2005f5cbe0bd

and

TestDriver, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

They are seen as completely different by the assembly loader. It looks to me like the problem you have here is that you referenced the strong named version of the assembly, but only have the unsigned version available.

If you are building TestDriver yourself, you need to make sure you have the public half of the key pair with which it will ultimately be signed available, and then check the "Delay sign only" box on the Signing page of the assembly properties in Visual Studio. This will build a version of TestDriver that has a public key token, but which is not in fact signed. At that point, disabling signature verification will be necessary, but once disabling, the assembly should load.

Comment: You are right, @Mike, I have misunderstand strong name a lot, a delay signed dll can't be loaded unless disable strong name verification; strong name is used for version only, and can't used to protect dll from hacking.