# Unit testing a signed assembly in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-signing

I'm attempting to write some unit tests for a strongly named assembly. The unit tests are in a UnitTests project, the code is in a Plugins project, and they are both part of the same solution. Plugins is strongly signed. UnitTests has a reference to Plugins and everything compiles nicely.

When I try to run a test the test fails with an exception, "Could not load file or assembly... Strong name validation failed"

If I disable signing for Plugins the tests work, but signing is required for how the plugins are used. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried signing the test project too?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I have tried the signing the test project as well. Used the same key, no change in the error.

Comment: I think you can turn it off with [sn.exe -vR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845222/how-to-use-sn-exe-vr) but I can't remember the syntax offhand..

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that it is somehow retaining the bad reference to the signed assembly. Have you tried a clean and then build? I find that VS can sometimes be finicky in these situations

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I've been trying variations on clean and got nothing. For a moment I thought an added InternalsVisibleTo line had solved it but that turned out to be a false positive since I hadn't cleaned UnitTests first.

Comment: Are you just using the VS Test Explorer, or are you using a runner like nCrunch?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Just VS Test Explorer

Comment: Your assemblies aren't delayed signed are they? Should be in the signing tab of project properties.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Just checked and Delay sign isn't checked under Signing and sign the assembly is checked. Also checked with sn though and got a message that, "Plugins.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145998/discussion-between-michael-coxon-and-ceribia).

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the result of another error I was encountering. Sometimes when building Plugins the build would fail with,

> Assembly signing failed; output may not be signed -- Error signing assembly -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Building again would more often than not fix this error. It turns out that on the second build the Plugins.dll would sometimes remain and be only delay signed. UnitTests would take this delay signed dll and understandably complain.

To check if this is the issue you are running into open up a developer command prompt and run, "sn -vf Plugins.dll". If the output is, "Plugins.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly", you may have the some problem.

The workaround that I am using is to repeatedly attempt to sign Plugins.dll until it works. To do this I first ran:

> sn -i ../../FakeXRMTesting.pfx keyContainer

To set up a key container so sn could work without a password. Next I set Plugins.dll to Delay Sign Only and added a post-build event

> :repeat
>
> C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SDKs"\Windows\v8.0A\bin\"NETFX 4.0 Tools"\sn.exe -Rc Plugins.dll keyContainer || goto :repeat

Normally it fails 4-5 before working. This is quite clearly a cludge and stopping whatever program is accessing the dll from doing so would be preferred.

Comment: Whatever anti-malware product you use, it is time to go shopping for another one.

Comment: @HansPassant Very likely, but I don't have permissions to prove it at the moment. I'll update once I've got proof it's the culprit.